Cannot hightlight active nav-item in Bootstrap-5
I'm trying to use the navbar in Bootstrap and highlight (change color) the nav-link on the active bar. However, it doesn't work. Also, I'm using Bootstrap-5.
Here is my CSS file:
.nav-link {
    color: #666777;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-link.active {
    color: red;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #000;
}


And here is my HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">My Webpage</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Hobby
                      </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/anime.html">Hobby1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/books.html">Hobby2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/vtubers.html">Hobby3</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
        </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>

When I change the href in the  tag to "#", for example: <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a> to <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>, it does change the color when I click it, but then I cannot navigate the user to another page.
I also tried to manually add the class .active to the appropriate nav-link in each file but it didn't work.
Thank you in advance.

I think you are using Bootstarp 5,but your HTML file includes Bootstarp 4 scripts .This might be causing some issues .For navigating user to another page I think you should put your file location in the place of # like "./nextPage.html" like that. Hope this might work for you

you have multiple issues with your provided code.

If we use bootstrap CDN, we need to add two links one of css & other of script. You have already added both but issue is your css is of version 5.3.3 and your script is of version 4.3, so need to fix that issue first.
If you want to override any bootstrap property, you always need to add !important to css.

I have fixed all of issues in below code:


.nav-link {
    color: #666777 ;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-item .active {
    color: red !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #000;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">My Webpage</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" href="/index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Hobby
                      </a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/anime.html">Hobby1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/books.html">Hobby2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/hobby/vtubers.html">Hobby3</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
        </header>




Your example works the same when using .nav-link.active instead of .nav-item .active

Thanks for letting me know, I did not checked that possibility.

Thank you so much for your answer, but when I changed my code as you said, there was one problem I ran into. The dropdown "Hobby" didn't work when I clicked it.

@Meet I just took a closer look and realized the reason why .nav-link.active works in your example is because you moved the .active class from the list item with the .nav-item class to the anchor with the .nav-link class. The reason it doesn't work in the OP is not only because it would be overruled by Bootstrap without the !important flag, but also because it did not match anything.

Edit: it turns out that I used the navbar of bootstrap-4, and when I copy the navbar from bootstrap-5, it is fixed.

@TimR Thank you for pointing out that, I just realized that in bootstrap-5 the .active class is moved to anchor with the .nav-link class while in bootstrap-4 it is in list with the .nav-item class

@TimR , I tried moving active back to nav-item also tried both css nav-item.active & nav-item .active & both didn't worked so I think this particular version of code will work with only nav-link. But at the end we all added some pieces to this puzzle and fixed the issue, that's commendable. @Muoi good job you also pointed one of the issue.
